# Get element value from XML datatype field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve element value from XML data field. Please check below code snippet for more detail:

SQL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (ConfigXSLT XML);

INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES('<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="transport">
    <transport protocol="FILE" direction="get" filename="file1*.csv" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>')

-- I want only filename element value 'file1*.csv' in select statement

-- I have tried with below query but it not works
SELECT ConfigXSLT.value('declare namespace PD="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"; (//PD:variable/PD:transport/PD:filename)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
FROM #Temp1

DROP TABLE #Temp1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went overboard with using PD namespace (why PD btw?), the "transport" telement is without a namespace. Also, to select attribute you use @ sign before the attributes name :)

Try this:

```
SELECT ConfigXSLT.value('declare namespace PD="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"; (//PD:variable/transport/@filename)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
FROM #Temp1
```

Result:

```
file1*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @xml.value('(/stylesheet/variable/transport/@filename)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: I have tried with this but not working. This code is not working stylesheet xmls.